# I am trying to call python using C# with the IronPython nuget

Tags: c#, ironpython

I am very new to this and require some help. I am trying to call something basic as per the section below using C# with the IronPython nuget.

Below is what I am trying:

```
 Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine py = Python.CreateEngine(); 
 Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope s = py.CreateScope(); 



py.Execute("import numpy as np incomes = np.random.normal(27000, 15000, 10000) x = np.mean(incomes)", s);
```

I keep receiving the following error: 
An exception of type 'Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException' occurred in Microsoft.Scripting.dll but was not handled in user code

Any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: you can use `pyinstaller` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware of indentation when working with Python. This works:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
namespace PythonFromCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine py = Python.CreateEngine();
            Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope s = py.CreateScope();

            // add paths to where your libs are installed
            var libs = new[] { @"c:\path\to\lib1", @"c:\path\to\lib2" };
            py.SetSearchPaths(libs);

            py.Execute(
@"import numpy as np 
incomes = np.random.normal(27000, 15000, 10000) 
x = np.mean(incomes)"
            , s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great advise. I still get the following error after:An exception of type 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' occurred in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Try adding paths to where numpy is installed. I updated my answer with an example on how to do that :)

Comment: This has been so helpful thank you. I have installed and added per your suggestion. I have made sure everything is up to date and installed correctly, but I get this error. unexpected token 'append' is there an issue with the way I set it up?

Comment: @JacobO'Brien Not sure why that is a problem, but I'd suggest you develop your python script in an other environment to start with and make sure that the script works as intended. Then you let your C# program open the file containing the script, instead of having it as part of the C# code. Indentation and line breaks are very important when it comes to python so make sure to get it right. I'd say that's much easier if you keep your script in a separate file rather than stored in a C# string.

Answer (score 1):

Your Python syntax is incorrect. Insert line breaks (`\n`)

```
py.Execute("import numpy as np\nincomes = np.random.normal(27000, 15000, 10000)\nx = np.mean(incomes)", s);
```

Comment: You, sir, are a legend! I have done that, but now get the following :An exception of type 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' occurred in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: You need to install numpy, try doing so using pip or a similar tool.